# Navigation_stack actionlib goal coordinates

Tags: ros, navigation, coordinates, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all

I have a navigation_stack implemented and working. And, I would like to send the goal coordinates in the code through a topic using actionlib. I dont want to send the goal coordinates through  rviz.

Does any one may have a chunk of code I can use or a site where I can read how to do this. I have been reading actionlib tutorials but I need a more specific implementation.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63316/navigation_stack-actionlib--goal-coordinates/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [tutorial SendingSimpleGoals](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals) explains exactly what you want to do. (Also check out the [other navigation tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/), they are quite good).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-05-24**:
The robot is working properly with the navigation_stack. I now want to move further. I can send the robot to some coordinates based on the tutorial you suggested (Using actionlib). However, I want to use actionlib to pass 2D Pose estimate and 2D Nav goal. Do you know how to do that?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-05-24**:
Yes, it's all explained in the tutorial I linked to.

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-06-04**:
Thank you It is working, :)